# ReferenceError: Location is not defined | Angular 15 SSR with nguniversal/express-engine

Tags: node.js, angular, express, npm, server-side-rendering

After running `npm run dev:ssr` build Compiled successfully.

Then `ReferenceError: Location is not defined` appeared.

this is the whole error...

```
ReferenceError: Location is not defined
    at Module.63370 (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:22723:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23113:42)
    at Module.84362 (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:22752:69)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23113:42)
    at Module.23149 (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:22789:80)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23113:42)
    at Module.53226 (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:22818:74)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23113:42)
    at /Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23131:85
    at Function.__webpack_require__.O (/Users/application/directory/dist/app/server/main.js:23161:23)

A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:65425



Angular CLI: 15.1.6
Node: 16.19.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
nguniversal/express-engine": "^15.2.1",
```